# CVMat dimension/size/shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opencv

I would like to get the dimensions of the `cv::Mat` object returned from `(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;` in an Iphone application where I use OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [Size()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-size) method of the `cv::Mat`

Comment: Here is what I have tried so far `NSLog(@"%ld", Size(image));` . Also syntax `SizeOf` did not work for me :(

Comment: I used `image.rows`, `image.cols` and `image.size` instead. Thanks!